# Ito's lemma and Stratonovich calculus

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I tried converting Ito's lemma to Stratonovich form, but I got inconsistent results.

Consider a 1-D SDE in both Ito and Stratonovich sense:
$$
dX_t = \mu(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dW_t
= \bar{\mu}(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) \circ dW_t,
$$
where
$$
\bar{\mu} = \mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma \sigma'. \qquad(1)
$$

Let $f=f(x)$ be a smooth function of $x$. For simplicity, $f, \mu$, and $\sigma$ have no time dependence. By Ito's lemma, we get
$$
df = 
\left( \mu f' + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f'' \right) dt + \sigma f' dW_t.
$$

Now, I want to transform the above equation into Stratonovich form, but I got inconsistent results. Here are my derivations.

###### 1. Using transformation formula

From Eq.(1), we have:
$$
\begin{align}
df &= 
\left[
\mu f' + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f'' 
- \frac{1}{2} \sigma f' \frac{\partial (\sigma f')}{\partial X}
\right] dt + \sigma f' \circ dW_t\\
&= 
\left[
\mu f' + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f'' 
- \frac{1}{2} \sigma \sigma' (f')^2 - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f' f''
\right] dt + \sigma f' \circ dW_t.
\qquad \qquad (2)
\end{align}
$$

###### 2. Using the chain fule for Stratonovich SDE

Since Stratonovich SDE follows the regular chain rule, we have
$$
\begin{align}
df 
&= f' \circ dX_t
= f' (\bar{\mu} dt + \sigma\circ dW_t ) \\
&= \left(
\mu f' - \frac{1}{2} \sigma \sigma' f'
\right) dt + \sigma f' \circ dW_t.
\qquad \qquad (3)
\end{align}
$$

It seems like these two results can't be identical, but I'm not sure where it goes wrong.

---

Edit: Corrected a few typos according to Kurt's comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transformation between Ito and Stratonovich calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428638/transformation-between-ito-and-stratonovich-calculus)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I didn't really see how it helps the current question. Do you think I need to derive a discrete summation in order to figure out which form is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4428638/transformation-between-ito-and-stratonovich-calculus) I show that for any process $Y_t$
whose stochastic integrals are defined we have
$$
\tag{1}
\underbrace{\int_0^tY_s\circ\,dW_s}_{\text{Stratonovich}}=\underbrace{\int_0^tY_s\,dW_s}_{\text{Ito}}+\tfrac{1}{2}\langle W,Y\rangle_t\,
$$
(the notation for $Y_s$ was $f(s)$ in the link).

In your case we have an Ito SDE
$$
dX_t=\mu\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t
$$
and we know
\begin{align}\tag{Ito}
df(X_t)&=f'(X_t)\,dX_t+\tfrac 12f''(X_t)\,d\langle X\rangle_t\\[2mm]
&=f'(X_t)\sigma(X_t)\,dW_t+f'(X_t)\mu(X_t)\,dt+\tfrac 12f''(X_t)\sigma^2(X_t)\,dt\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
***Claim:***
$$\tag{3}
df=f'\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma\sigma'}{2}\,dt\right)+f'\sigma\circ dW_t\,.
$$
*In particular, if $\mu\equiv 0$ and $\sigma\equiv 1$ then $X_t$ is
a Brownian motion and
the Stratonovich calculus follows the rules of ordinary calculus:*
$$\tag{Stratonovich}
\boxed{\quad df(W_t)=f'(W_t)\circ\,dW_t\,.\phantom{\Big|}\quad}
$$
Proof. Writing
$$
\alpha(X_t)=\sigma(X_t)f'(X_t)
$$
we get from Ito
$$
d\alpha=\alpha'\,dX_t+\frac{\alpha''}{2}\,d\langle X\rangle_t\,.
$$
Using $Y_t=\alpha(X_t)$ and (2)
this means
$$\tag{4}
d\langle Y,W\rangle_t=\alpha'(X_t)\,\sigma(X_t)\,dt=\Big(\sigma\,\sigma'\,f'+\sigma^2\,f''\Big)(X_t)\,dt\,.
$$
Using now (1), (2) and (4) we get (3).
$$\tag*{$\Box$}
\quad
$$
To answer the question where your mistake was:

- In short: in your equation (2) you have too many $f'\,.$
- Up to a typo you have correctly from Ito
  $$\tag{5}
  df=\left(\mu f'+\frac12\sigma^{\color{red}2}f''\right)\,dt+\sigma f'\,dW_t\,.
  $$
- When going to $\sigma f'\circ dW_t$ you follow the pattern
  $$
  \mu\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t=\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma\sigma'}{2}\right)\,dt+
  \sigma\circ dW_t
  $$
  which is correct for $dX_t$ but not for $df(X_t)\,.$
- This incorrect approach leads to
  \begin{align}\tag{incorrect}
  df&=\left(\mu f'+\frac12\sigma^2 f''-\frac{\sigma f'(\sigma f')'}2\right)\,dt+\sigma f'\circ dW_t\\
  &=\left(\mu f'+\frac12\sigma^2 f''-\frac{\sigma\sigma'(f')^\color{red}{2}+\sigma^2f' f''}2\right)\,dt+\sigma f'\circ dW_t\\
  \end{align}
  where $\sigma^2$-terms don't cancel and the $\sigma\sigma'$ term has
  one $f'$ too many.
- The correct
  step from (5) to (3) is to use the expression (4) which accounts via (1)
  for another drift change when going from $\sigma f'dW_t$ to
  $\sigma f'\circ dW_t\,.$
- I have to say that this was new and surprising to me. Every time I look
  at Stratonovich I learn something new.

Comment: Your nice presentation (1) solved one of my question, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand your derivation. However, could you point out which part is wrong in the derivation of my Eq.(2)?

Comment: @Fred please number all your equatios so that we can better address these problems. One I see already: your $\frac12\sigma f''$ should be $\frac12\sigma^2f''\,.$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have corrected this typo and I will remember to number all my equations in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kurt's answer and comment, the mistake I made in Eq. (2) in the post can be resolved in an alternative way below.

From Ito's lemma, we have
$$
df = 
\left( \mu f' + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f'' \right) dt + \sigma f' dW_t.
\qquad\qquad(1)
$$

To calculate its Stratonovich form, what we actually need is:
$$
\begin{align}
df &= 
\left[
\mu f' + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f'' 
- \frac{1}{2} \sigma f' \frac{\partial (\sigma f')}{\partial {\color{red}{f}}}
\right] dt + \sigma f' \circ dW_t.
\qquad(2)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma f' \frac{\partial (\sigma f')}{\partial {f}}
&= \sigma f' \frac{\partial (\sigma f')}{\partial X} \frac{\partial X}{\partial f}
= \sigma f' (\sigma' f' + \sigma f'') / f'
= \sigma (\sigma' f' + \sigma f'').
\qquad(3)
\end{align}
$$
Plug it back to Eq.(2), we get:
$$
df = \left( \mu f' - \dfrac{1}{2}\sigma \sigma' f' \right) dt
+ \sigma f' \circ dW_t,
$$
which is consistent with the other method.

Comment: Really nice! Every coin has two sides and you found one that shines.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from Kurt's answer to Fred's answer why $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}$ is legitimate. I write a detailed explanation here.
The Ito $\Leftrightarrow$ Stratonovich conversion is only valid when $dX_t$ is an expression of the following form $$dX_t=\mu(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t) dW_t\Leftrightarrow dX_t=\bar{\mu}(X_t,t)+\sigma(X_t,t)\circ dW_t$$

Clearly $$df(X_t)=\left(\mu(X_t,t)f'(X_t)+\frac12\sigma^2(X_t,t)f''(X_t,t)\right)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)f'(X_t)dW_t$$
is not in this form. So the conversion formula does not apply. If we let $Y_t=f(X_t)$, the coefficients of the righthand side should involve $Y_t$ only and then we can apply the conversion formula. To see this, assuming $f$ is invertible. Then we have
$$x=f^{-1}(y):=s(y)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(f^{-1})'(y)}:=g(y)$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac{(f^{-1})''y}{((f^{-1})'(y))^3}:=h(y)$$
Via these conversions, we can rewrite the righthand side of the expression involving $Y_t$ only as

$$dY_t=\left(\mu(s(Y_t),t)g(Y_t)+\frac12\sigma^2(s(Y_t),t)h(Y_t)\right)dt+\sigma(s(Y_t),t)g(Y_t)dW_t$$
This form is consistent with Ito $\Leftrightarrow$ Stratonovich conversion, so we can apply the rule

$$dY_t=\left(\mu(s(Y_t),t)g(Y_t)+\frac12\sigma^2(s(Y_t),t)h(Y_t)-\frac12\left(\sigma(s(Y_t),t)g(Y_t)\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\sigma(s(Y_t),t)g(Y_t)\right)\right)dt+\left(\sigma(s(Y_t),t)g(Y_t)\right)\circ dW_t$$

This expression is exactly the same as Fred's correction

$$
\begin{align}
df &= 
\left[
\mu f' + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 f'' 
- \frac{1}{2} \sigma f' \frac{\partial (\sigma f')}{\partial {\color{red}{f}}}
\right] dt + \sigma f' \circ dW_t.
\qquad(2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I just made a hand-waving there, but your answer proves that doing such is legitimate!